# How to append the method name to the end tag in vim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

I'm trying to modify [endwise](https://github.com/tpope/vim-endwise) which already appends an "end" on a new line after I type

```
def my_func
```

So I end up with

```
def my_func

end
```

What I want to do, is update the code so that I end up with

```
def my_func

end # </ "my_func" >
```

This will show me what the end is for, which will help confusion when looking at nested dos/whiles/defs

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Rather than littering these things all over your code, I would suggest using [textobj-rubyblock](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3382) or [ruby-matchit.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=290) so you can press `%` to jump to the matching keyword or `end`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a snippet engine. Nowadays, all of them support some kind of synchronized placeholders. Fill in the blanks at one place, they'll get filled at other places.